# how to set custom colors in pie 3D Chart using Apache poi 4.1.2

Tags: java, apache-poi, pie-chart

I have created PIE 3D chart using POI 4.1.2. and need to have specific colors for each legend entry
[expected like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibiSJ.png)

the code I used is here,

```html
final XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet2.createDrawingPatriarch();
            final XSSFClientAnchor anchor =
                    drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 7, 20);
            

            final XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
            chart.setTitleText("Unit Build Procurement");
            chart.setTitleOverlay(false);

            final XDDFChartLegend legend = chart.getOrAddLegend();
            legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.TOP_RIGHT);

            final XDDFDataSource<String> dataSource =
                    XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange(sheet2,
                            new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 0, 3));

            final XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> values =
                    XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet2,
                            new CellRangeAddress(1, sheet2.getLastRowNum(), 0,
                                    3));

            final XDDFChartData data =
                    chart.createData(ChartTypes.PIE3D, null, null);
            data.setVaryColors(true);
            data.addSeries(dataSource, values);
            chart.plot(data);
```

It creates chart with random colors.

thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `XDDF` method to set data point colors until now. Only series colors can be set using `XDDF` methods. So one must use the underlying `org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.*` classes. Following complete example shows this. It sets data point colors from a bunch of formerly set rgb byte arrays.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.ChartTypes;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.LegendPosition;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFChartData;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFChartLegend;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFDataSource;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFDataSourcesFactory;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFNumericalDataSource;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFPieChartData;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFChart;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFClientAnchor;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFDrawing;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class Pie3DChart {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Object[][] data = new Object[][] {
     new Object[] {"Country", "Count"},
     new Object[] {"India", 13d},
     new Object[] {"USA", 5d},
     new Object[] {"England", 12d},
     new Object[] {"South Africa", 10d}
    };
    
    try (XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
      XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("piechart");
      final int NUM_OF_ROWS = data.length;
      final int NUM_OF_COLUMNS = 2;

      // create sheet data
      Row row;
      Cell cell;
      for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < NUM_OF_ROWS; rowIndex++) {
        row = sheet.createRow((short) rowIndex);
        for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < NUM_OF_COLUMNS; colIndex++) {
          cell = row.createCell((short) colIndex);
          Object cellValue = data[rowIndex][colIndex];
          if (cellValue instanceof String) {
            cell.setCellValue((String)cellValue);
          } else if (cellValue instanceof Double) {
            cell.setCellValue((Double)cellValue);
          }
        }
      }

      // create drawing and anchor
      XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
      XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 12, 15);

      // create chart
      XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
      chart.setTitleText("Countries");
      chart.setTitleOverlay(false);
      XDDFChartLegend legend = chart.getOrAddLegend();
      legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.TOP_RIGHT);

      XDDFDataSource<String> cat = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange(sheet,
          new CellRangeAddress(1, NUM_OF_ROWS - 1, 0, 0));
      XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> val = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet,
          new CellRangeAddress(1, NUM_OF_ROWS - 1, 1, 1));

      XDDFChartData chartData = chart.createData(ChartTypes.PIE3D, null, null);
      chartData.setVaryColors(true);
      XDDFChartData.Series series = chartData.addSeries(cat, val);
      chart.plot(chartData);

      // do not auto delete the title; is necessary for showing title in Calc
      if (chart.getCTChart().getAutoTitleDeleted() == null) chart.getCTChart().addNewAutoTitleDeleted();
      chart.getCTChart().getAutoTitleDeleted().setVal(false);

      // data point colors; is necessary for showing data points in Calc
      // some rgb colors to choose
      byte[][] colors = new byte[][] {
        new byte[] {127,(byte)255, 127},
        new byte[] {(byte)200, (byte)200, (byte)200},
        new byte[] {(byte)255,(byte)255, 127},
        new byte[] {(byte)255, 127, 127},
        new byte[] {(byte)255, 0, 0},
        new byte[] {0, (byte)255, 0},
        new byte[] {0, 0, (byte)255},
        new byte[] {80, 80, 80}
      };
      // set data point colors
      int pointCount = series.getCategoryData().getPointCount();
      for (int p = 0; p < pointCount; p++) {
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPie3DChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).addNewDPt().addNewIdx().setVal(p);
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPie3DChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDPtArray(p)
          .addNewSpPr().addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(colors[p]);
      }
 
      // write the output to a file
      try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("ooxml-pie-chart.xlsx")) {
        wb.write(fileOut);
      }
    }
  }
}
```