# Color BarChart bars depending on data using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, bar-chart

I'm trying to set the fill color of each individual bar of my chart to a separate custom color but I have yet to discover how.

Here's my code so far. The layout is fine but the chart bars are all the same color (cornflower blue). I'm aware that I can use the XDDFChartData:setVaryColors option to use different colors but I can't find a way to specify which colors to use (say in my example 'Books' in red, 'DVDs' in blue, etc.).

```
final Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
final Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("MySheet");

Row row = sheet.createRow(1);

Cell cell = row.createCell(1);
cell.setCellValue("Product");

cell = row.createCell(2);
cell.setCellValue("Orders");

row = sheet.createRow(2);

cell = row.createCell(1);
cell.setCellValue("Books");

cell = row.createCell(2);
cell.setCellValue(50);

row = sheet.createRow(3);

cell = row.createCell(1);
cell.setCellValue("DVDs");

cell = row.createCell(2);
cell.setCellValue(25);

row = sheet.createRow(4);

cell = row.createCell(1);
cell.setCellValue("CDs");

cell = row.createCell(2);
cell.setCellValue(140);

XSSFDrawing drawing = ((XSSFSheet) sheet).createDrawingPatriarch();
XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 12, 15 );

XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
chart.setTitleText("Products");
chart.setTitleOverlay(false);

CTBoolean FALSE = CTBoolean.Factory.newInstance();
FALSE.setVal(false);
chart.getCTChartSpace().setRoundedCorners(FALSE);

XDDFCategoryAxis bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
bottomAxis.setMajorTickMark(AxisTickMark.NONE);

XDDFValueAxis leftAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);
leftAxis.setCrossBetween(AxisCrossBetween.BETWEEN);

XDDFDataSource<String> compliances = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange((XSSFSheet) sheet, new CellRangeAddress(2, 4, 1, 1));

XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> components = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange((XSSFSheet) sheet, new CellRangeAddress(2, 4, 2, 2));

XDDFChartData data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.BAR, bottomAxis, leftAxis);

XDDFChartData.Series series1 = data.addSeries(compliances, components);
series1.setTitle("Components by Compliance", null);

chart.plot(data);

XDDFBarChartData bar = (XDDFBarChartData) data;
bar.setBarDirection(BarDirection.BAR);

CTSRgbColor rgb = CTSRgbColor.Factory.newInstance();

Color col1 = new Color(100, 149, 237);
rgb.setVal(new byte[]{(byte) col1.getRed(), (byte) col1.getGreen(), (byte) col1.getBlue()});

CTSolidColorFillProperties fillProp = CTSolidColorFillProperties.Factory.newInstance();
fillProp.setSrgbClr(rgb);

CTShapeProperties ctShapeProperties = CTShapeProperties.Factory.newInstance();
ctShapeProperties.setSolidFill(fillProp);
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getBarChartList().get(0).getSerList().get(0).setSpPr(ctShapeProperties);

IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach(sheet::autoSizeColumn);
```

Any ideas?

Cheers!

Comment: The `apache poi` example https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/examples/xssf/usermodel/BarChart.java provides `private static void solidFillSeries(XDDFChartData data, int index, PresetColor color)` to set bar colors.

Comment: So one can only color bars on a per-series basis? My chart only has one series. I would have thought that this would be doable. I can manually specify colors in Excel after all...

Comment: If it is the case that you are limited to one color per series (and it seems that it is), you could create one series per data item (or one series per desired color). I've had to do that before with other chart libraries with similar restrictions. It's an onerous hack, but sometimes you have to do what you have to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as if you wants coloring each data point instead of the bar series. If so then this is the same problem as with [how to set custom colors in pie 3D Chart using Apache poi 4.1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66226211/how-to-set-custom-colors-in-pie-3d-chart-using-apache-poi-4-1-2/66229491#66229491). Difference is only the chart type.

There is no `XDDF` method to set data point colors until now. Only series colors can be set using `XDDF` methods. So one must use the underlying `org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.*` classes. Following complete example shows this. It sets data point colors from a bunch of formerly set rgb byte arrays.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.*;

public class BarChartOneSeries {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    final Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("MySheet");

    Row row = sheet.createRow(1);

    Cell cell = row.createCell(1);
    cell.setCellValue("Product");

    cell = row.createCell(2);
    cell.setCellValue("Orders");

    row = sheet.createRow(2);

    cell = row.createCell(1);
    cell.setCellValue("Books");

    cell = row.createCell(2);
    cell.setCellValue(50);

    row = sheet.createRow(3);

    cell = row.createCell(1);
    cell.setCellValue("DVDs");

    cell = row.createCell(2);
    cell.setCellValue(25);

    row = sheet.createRow(4);

    cell = row.createCell(1);
    cell.setCellValue("CDs");

    cell = row.createCell(2);
    cell.setCellValue(140);

    XSSFDrawing drawing = ((XSSFSheet) sheet).createDrawingPatriarch();
    XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 12, 15 );

    XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
    chart.setTitleText("Products");
    chart.setTitleOverlay(false);

    CTBoolean FALSE = CTBoolean.Factory.newInstance();
    FALSE.setVal(false);
    chart.getCTChartSpace().setRoundedCorners(FALSE);

    XDDFCategoryAxis bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    bottomAxis.setMajorTickMark(AxisTickMark.NONE);

    XDDFValueAxis leftAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
    leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);
    leftAxis.setCrossBetween(AxisCrossBetween.BETWEEN);

    XDDFDataSource<String> compliances = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange((XSSFSheet) sheet, new CellRangeAddress(2, 4, 1, 1));

    XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> components = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange((XSSFSheet) sheet, new CellRangeAddress(2, 4, 2, 2));

    XDDFChartData data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.BAR, bottomAxis, leftAxis);

    XDDFChartData.Series series = data.addSeries(compliances, components);
    series.setTitle("Components by Compliance", null);

    chart.plot(data);

    XDDFBarChartData bar = (XDDFBarChartData) data;
    bar.setBarDirection(BarDirection.BAR);


    // do not auto delete the title; is necessary for showing title in Calc
    if (chart.getCTChart().getAutoTitleDeleted() == null) chart.getCTChart().addNewAutoTitleDeleted();
    chart.getCTChart().getAutoTitleDeleted().setVal(false);

    // data point colors; is necessary for showing data points in Calc
    // some rgb colors to choose
    byte[][] colors = new byte[][] {
      new byte[] {127,(byte)255, 127},
      new byte[] {(byte)200, (byte)200, (byte)200},
      new byte[] {(byte)255,(byte)255, 127},
      new byte[] {(byte)255, 127, 127},
      new byte[] {(byte)255, 0, 0},
      new byte[] {0, (byte)255, 0},
      new byte[] {0, 0, (byte)255},
      new byte[] {80, 80, 80}
    };
    // set data point colors
    int pointCount = series.getCategoryData().getPointCount();
    for (int p = 0; p < pointCount; p++) {
      chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getBarChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).addNewDPt().addNewIdx().setVal(p);
      chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getBarChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDPtArray(p)
        .addNewSpPr().addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(colors[p]);
    }
    // write the output to a file
    try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("ooxml-bar-chart.xlsx")) {
      workbook.write(fileOut);
    }
    workbook.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm my IDE can't find CTDLbls. Is there a different dependency for that ? I'm using org.apache.poi/poi and org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml in version 5.0.0.

Comment: See https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10025

Comment: This works and is preferable to the multi-series approach. Many thanks!